# How do I create a calculation to view difference while adding a filter for an area code in Tableau?

Tags: plot, filter, tableau-api

[image: Image of my viz so far]

Hi, I am new to tableau and working on a project:

I have created a dumbell chart viz where total population is displayed between 2 years 2014 and 2017 for about 70 zip codes.

I want to add a filter such that only the top 10 zip codes are shown which have the greatest decrease in population 2014-2017.

Will a calculated field be required for this? Or is there a simple way to just filter?

For example, I have filtered by Top 10 - variance but it is showing me incorrect figures

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to use a calculated field and [LOD (Level of Detail) expressions](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.htm) to determine the difference in population between the years.

1. Create a calculated field under Measures called "Population Change". Use the following code:

```html
{ FIXED [Zip] : SUM(IIF(YEAR([Year]) = 2017, [Total Population], NULL)) } -
    { FIXED [Zip] : SUM(IIF(YEAR([Year]) = 2014, [Total Population], NULL)) }
```

2. Drag Zip onto Filters. In the window that comes up, select the "Top" tab, then the "By Field" radio button, then "Bottom 10 by Population Change Sum"

[Screenshot of this in Tableau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w750D.png)

Going forward, if you have more than just 2014 and 2017's data, you can create a parameter for start year and end year then use those in the calculated field instead of hard coding them.